# Create a mask from a bitmap and transparency color - Windows GDI

Tags: c, windows, winapi, gdi

Here’s the code I've spent the past two days trying to debug:

```
#include <windows.h>

HBITMAP createImageMask(HBITMAP bitmapHandle, const COLORREF transparencyColor) {
    // For getting information about the bitmap's height and width in this context
    BITMAP bitmap;

    // Create the device contexts for the bitmap and its mask
    HDC bitmapGraphicsDeviceContext = CreateCompatibleDC(NULL);
    HDC bitmapMaskGraphicsDeviceContext = CreateCompatibleDC(NULL);

    // For the device contexts to re-select the initial object they initialized with
    // and de-select the bitmap and mask
    HGDIOBJ bitmapDummyObject;
    HGDIOBJ bitmapMaskDummyObject;

    // The actual mask
    HBITMAP bitmapMaskHandle;

    // 1. Generate the mask.
    GetObject(bitmapHandle, sizeof(BITMAP), &bitmap);
    bitmapMaskHandle = CreateBitmap(bitmap.bmWidth, bitmap.bmHeight, 1, 1, NULL);

    // 2. Setup the device context for the mask (and the bitmap)
    //    — also get the initial selected objects in the device contexts.
    bitmapDummyObject = SelectObject(bitmapGraphicsDeviceContext, (HGDIOBJ) (HBITMAP) bitmapHandle);
    bitmapMaskDummyObject = SelectObject(bitmapMaskGraphicsDeviceContext, (HGDIOBJ) (HBITMAP) bitmapMaskHandle);

    // 3. Set the background color of the mask.
    SetBkColor(bitmapGraphicsDeviceContext, transparencyColor);

    // 4. Copy the bitmap to the mask and invert it so it blends with the background color.
    BitBlt(bitmapMaskGraphicsDeviceContext, 0, 0, bitmap.bmWidth, bitmap.bmHeight, bitmapGraphicsDeviceContext, 0, 0, SRCCOPY);
    BitBlt(bitmapGraphicsDeviceContext, 0, 0, bitmap.bmWidth, bitmap.bmHeight, bitmapMaskGraphicsDeviceContext, 0, 0, SRCINVERT);

    // 5. Select the bitmaps out before deleting the device contexts to avoid any issues.
    SelectObject(bitmapGraphicsDeviceContext, bitmapDummyObject);
    SelectObject(bitmapMaskGraphicsDeviceContext, bitmapMaskDummyObject);

    // Clean-up
    DeleteDC(bitmapGraphicsDeviceContext);
    DeleteDC(bitmapMaskGraphicsDeviceContext);

    // Voila!
    return bitmapMaskHandle;
}
```

It creates a bitmap handle (`HBITMAP`) and doesn't generate any errors (from the `GetLastError` function).

---

Problem: It doesn't generate a monochrome version of the bitmap I applied to it, 
rather it just creates a bitmap that's only filled with black.

So what's up with the code, what am I doing wrong? 
Or how do I properly create bitmap masks?

(I’m attempting to do this without GDI+ or other libraries, if possible)

---

Here’s the image where the transparency color is red (`RGB(255, 0, 0)`):

[image]

Here’s the image mask (expected result then actual result respectively (left-to-right)):

[image]
[image]

---

References here:  [theForger’s Win32 API Programming Tutorial - Transparent Bitmaps](http://www.winprog.org/tutorial/transparency.html)

Comment: It would appear the code originates from http://www.winprog.org/tutorial/transparency.html. Did you make sure that "the bitmap isn't selected in to another HDC when you call this function"?

Comment: @GSerg: In my code the bitmap is loaded from a file with no reference to any HDCs. Then the  mask bitmap is created afterward using the function `createImageMask` before both the mask then the bitmap are selected into HDCs.

Comment: `bitmapMaskHandle` is still selected into `bitmapMaskGraphicsDeviceContext` when you delete that device context.  I think modern versions of GDI have gotten pretty forgiving of this, but technically it's a violation of the API.  You should select it back out before you delete the DC.  Also, show us the painting code.  Your mask is a monochrome bitmap, and it's easy to make mistakes when trying to display those.

Comment: @AdrianMcCarthy: By *"select it back out before you delete ..."* Do you mean `SelectObject(hdc, myMask)` then `SelectObject(hdc, someDummyObject)`?

Comment: `SelectObject` returns the old object. Save it and then reselect it back in when you're done.

Comment: @AdrianMcCarthy: I've updated the source code (and the question) with your suggestion but no progress so far... Here's the original code with the painting procedure (which I feel is a bit much to add to the question) https://github.com/LapysDev/Learning-Projects/tree/master/Technologies/C%2B%2B/Graphics/Win32%20API%20and%20Windows%20GDI/Image

Comment: @AdrianMcCarthy: If you've got a working version of the solution, I'd love to see it and see where I've made a mistake in the code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This code works, although it is not doing exactly what you think it is doing. If you are not seeing any output, whatever the problem is is external to this one function.

What this code is doing is setting up two bitmaps for use by an old Win32 technique for painting a sprite in which you use two calls to BitBlt with different  raster-operation codes, one painting a mask and one painting the sprite such that the sprite's background will not be painted. Note that it is *both creating a mask and also altering the source bitmap*. (That "const" in "const HBITMAP bitmapHandle" is not really doing anything. A bitmap handle is like a resource ID referring to a bitmap managed by Windows in a way that C++ knows nothing about. Making one const does not mean the bitmap to which it refers cannot be altered.) If you look at the code, the final BitBlit is blitting into the source bitmap, not the mask. What this call is doing is blacking out the key color in the source bitmap, which is what is required to paint a sprite using rop codes and two blits.

This technique by the way is an extremely old way of doing this, superceded by the introduction of [MaskBlt](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wingdi/nf-wingdi-maskblt) into the API, which will do what you want in one call. But even further, MaskBlt at this point is out-dated. You probably want to paint sprites for a game or something game-like. Almost certainly What you actually want is to load PNGs with per-pixel alpha and paint them with alpha compositing. You can do this with [GDI+](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/gdiplus/-gdiplus-gdi-start) or with an open source graphics library such as [FreeImage](http://freeimage.sourceforge.net/).

In any case below is minimal code that demonstrates this mask code actually works. Just change the following source such that "D:\test\hex_badge.bmp" is a path to wherever you have that hexagonal bitmap in your question.

```
#include <windows.h>

LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hWnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam);

HBITMAP g_bmp;
HBITMAP g_bmpMask;

HBITMAP createImageMask( HBITMAP bitmapHandle, const COLORREF transparencyColor) {
    // For getting information about the bitmap's height and width in this context
    BITMAP bitmap;

    // Create the device contexts for the bitmap and its mask
    HDC bitmapGraphicsDeviceContext = CreateCompatibleDC(NULL);
    HDC bitmapMaskGraphicsDeviceContext = CreateCompatibleDC(NULL);

    // The actual mask
    HBITMAP bitmapMaskHandle;

    // 1. Generate the mask.
    GetObject(bitmapHandle, sizeof(BITMAP), &bitmap);
    bitmapMaskHandle = CreateBitmap(bitmap.bmWidth, bitmap.bmHeight, 1, 1, NULL);

    // 2. Setup the device context for the mask (and the bitmap).
    SelectObject(bitmapGraphicsDeviceContext, bitmapHandle);
    SelectObject(bitmapMaskGraphicsDeviceContext, bitmapMaskHandle);

    // 3. Set the background color of the mask.
    SetBkColor(bitmapGraphicsDeviceContext, transparencyColor);

    // 4. Copy the bitmap to the mask and invert it so it blends with the background color.
    BitBlt(bitmapMaskGraphicsDeviceContext, 0, 0, bitmap.bmWidth, bitmap.bmHeight, bitmapGraphicsDeviceContext, 0, 0, SRCCOPY);
    BitBlt(bitmapGraphicsDeviceContext, 0, 0, bitmap.bmWidth, bitmap.bmHeight, bitmapMaskGraphicsDeviceContext, 0, 0, SRCINVERT);

    // Clean-up
    DeleteDC(bitmapGraphicsDeviceContext);
    DeleteDC(bitmapMaskGraphicsDeviceContext);

    // Voila!
    return bitmapMaskHandle;
}

int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, LPSTR lpCmdLine, int nCmdShow)
{

    MSG msg = { 0 };
    WNDCLASS wc = { 0 };
    wc.lpfnWndProc = WndProc;
    wc.hInstance = hInstance;
    wc.hbrBackground = (HBRUSH)(COLOR_BACKGROUND);
    wc.lpszClassName = L"minwindowsapp";

    g_bmp = (HBITMAP)LoadImage(hInstance, L"D:\\test\\hex_badge.bmp", IMAGE_BITMAP, 0, 0, LR_LOADFROMFILE);
    g_bmpMask = createImageMask(g_bmp, RGB(255, 0, 0));

    if (!RegisterClass(&wc))
        return 1;

    if (!CreateWindow(wc.lpszClassName,
        L"Minimal Windows Application",
        WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW | WS_VISIBLE,
        0, 0, 640, 480, 0, 0, hInstance, NULL))
        return 2;

    while (GetMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0) > 0) {
        TranslateMessage(&msg);
        DispatchMessage(&msg);
    }
    return 0;
}

LRESULT HandleWmPaint(HWND hWnd, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    PAINTSTRUCT ps;

    HDC hdcScr = GetDC(NULL);
    HDC hdcBmp = CreateCompatibleDC(hdcScr);
    HBITMAP hbmOld = (HBITMAP)SelectObject(hdcBmp, g_bmp);

    HDC hdcMask = CreateCompatibleDC(hdcScr);
    HBITMAP hbmOldMask = (HBITMAP) SelectObject(hdcMask, g_bmpMask );

    HDC hdc = BeginPaint(hWnd, &ps);
    BitBlt(hdc, 0, 0, 184, 184, hdcMask, 0, 0, SRCCOPY);
    BitBlt(hdc, 184, 0, 184, 184, hdcBmp, 0, 0, SRCCOPY);
    EndPaint(hWnd, &ps);

    SelectObject(hdcMask, hbmOldMask);
    DeleteDC(hdcMask);

    SelectObject(hdcBmp, hbmOld);
    DeleteDC(hdcBmp);
    ReleaseDC(NULL, hdcScr);

    return 0;
}

LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hWnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{

    switch (message)
    {
    case WM_CLOSE:
        PostQuitMessage(0);
        break;

    case WM_PAINT:
         return HandleWmPaint(hWnd, wParam, lParam);

    default:
        return DefWindowProc(hWnd, message, wParam, lParam);
    }
    return 0;
```

output is as below:

[image]

I'm not sure why exactly you are not getting output but most likely you are either not successfully loading the bitmap or you are not successfully painting to the screen.

Comment: I actually copied-and-pasted the example code in your answer out of frustration, and yet the the results were still the same as before (I think my Windows is broken)

Comment: I'll try another approach, thanks for helping out @jwezorek.

Comment: I actually wrote a blog post about using FreeImage for this sort of thing a long time ago. http://jwezorek.com/2012/02/blitting-with-per-pixel-in-alpha-in-win32/

Comment: Checking it out now